# ¿Por qué no funcionan mis archivos javascript en mi proyecto ASP .Net MVC 5(razor)

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

He querido darle formato a mi web. Primero descargué una página completa para extraer sus estilos. Extraje lo que quise y modifiqué lo que quise,también.

Cuando ya tenía lo que quería(IMG de la izquierda) empecé a trasladarlo a mi proyecto MVC en Visual Studio. Estoy seguro de haber copiado lo necesario(hasta donde yo creo) pero algunos CSS y Javascript no se aplican. Incluso dice que algunos archivos Javascript tienen errores.

**¿Cómo es posible que estos mismos archivos estaban funcionando en el archivo HTML y cuando compilo mi web MVC en el navegador,me dice que mis JS tienen errores?**

Estoy casi seguro que es por eso que no me salen algunos estilos(porque algunos los genera los archivos JS en conflicto)

*Lo que desarrollo es el pié de página en el `_Layout.cshtml`*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Duda en tu archivo .cshtml estas utilizando el  @Scripts.Render("~/rutascript") y  @Styles.Render("~/rutaCSS") ????

Comment: @J.Carlos Puedes mostrar el código y una imagen de la organización de tus carpetas css y js, es posible que la forma que haces la llamada al archivo sea incorrecta, o estos estén excluidos del proyecto y al publicar generen errores.

Comment: Si descargaste un Template, muchas veces los .css y los .js son llamados desde las páginas por una ruta que ya el desarrollador del Template puso,  a la hora de copiarlos, tienes que tener en cuenta que si los colocas en otras carpetas con otras rutas puede ser que no te sirva.

Comment: Te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por [ask] para poder ayudarte, ya que tu pregunta carece de un [mcve] que alguien pueda analizar y dar con la respuesta que necesitas. ¡No olvides también darte una vuelta por el [tour] del sitio para comprender mejor cómo funciona el sitio!

Answer (score 0):

No comprendí del todo tu duda, pero quizás pueda ayudarte esto. Hace algún tiempo me paso algo similar, estuve agregando contenido para un elemento en especifico de la pagina (por medio del ID de casa uno de estos) y analizando un poco el script generado me percate que el mismo visual al compilar los elementos de ADO.net agrega un prefijo para estos (cada id que coloquemos para ser mas específicos) que nosotros demos un id especifico.

por ejemplo en nuestro editor de visual si tenemos lo siguiente:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

al verlo compilado el id del input no sera "TextBox1" sino una variación de este mas un prefijo.

aplicando esta lógica quizás te este sucediendo algo similar.